# backbone.js 0.9.2 adding models with duplicate id's to a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm running into an issue where I have a collection that combines two different models (folders and items). When the models are fetched from the server, it is possible for a folder and item to have the same id. On fetch success I call collection.reset with the results from the server in order to add the items to the collection, but this causes one of the models to get removed because it is a duplicate (collection.reset calls collection.add and it finds two of the model id's are the same). Is there something (other than the models) I can change to solve this? I know that modelId was introduced in 1.2, but I'm unable to upgrade from 0.9.2.

Answer (score 2):

The Backbone id needs to be unique, assuming you intend to maintain data with duplicate ids, and you can't change the name of the attribute in the server API, I'd suggest you tell Backbone to use a different ID.

```js
var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Backbone.Model.extend({
     idAttribute: '_id'
    })
});

var col = new Collection([{id: 1, name: 'a'},{id: 1, name: 'b'}]);

$('#result').text(JSON.stringify(col.toJSON()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="result"/>
```

If instead you want to catch the data coming back from the server and reconcile the duplicate IDs, then you can use [Model.parse](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/0.9.2/index.html#Model-parse) to prefix the ID with some value depending on the data (e.g. "folder-" and "item-"). Then you call:

```
collection.reset(mixedModels, {parse: true});
```

Comment: Favor on-site stack snippets over off-site services like jsfiddle when possible.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not using the built in "show console" option?

Comment: I had it JSFiddle first and that doesn't have a console, no particular reason really